# Oracle function based index using LTRIM?

Tags: sql, oracle

Anyone created a function based index in oracle using LTRIM. Can you only use it with LTRIM function name and without the position parameter. I can create it like below, but not with a position parm.

```
CREATE INDEX GIS1.IX_GIS_DOCVERSION_FUNCTION_02
    ON GIS1.DOCVERSION(LTRIM("UBAB8_ORDERNUMBER")
)
TABLESPACE TS_GIS1
LOGGING
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
MAXTRANS 255
STORAGE(INITIAL 64K
        BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
NOPARALLEL
NOCOMPRESS
/
```

Comment: The Oracle `LTRIM` function does not take a "position" parameter. The second argument is a list of characters to be removed from the beginning of the first argument. If the second argument is omitted, the default is a space character.

Answer (score -1):

I found that you can add the position like below.

```
CREATE INDEX GIS1.IX_GIS_DOCVERSION_FUNCTION_02
    ON GIS1.DOCVERSION(LTRIM("UBAB8_ORDERNUMBER",'0')
)
TABLESPACE TS_GIS1
LOGGING
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
MAXTRANS 255
STORAGE(INITIAL 64K
        BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
NOPARALLEL
NOCOMPRESS
/
```

Comment: It isn't a position, it is a list of characters to be trimmed from the left of the input string - in your case all leading zeroes will be removed.